# Ionic 3 radio-group not binding selected item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have a radio-group ion-list element which is simply a normal hmtl radio-group warpped in a custom ionic angular component for presentaion. Thus far it works given the following:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedAddress">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let address of userAddresses">
        <ion-label>{{address.Street}}, {{address.Suburb}}, {{address.City}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="{{address.RefAddress}}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The data I used to populate this is a collection of Address objects implementing the following interface:

```
export interface Address {
   RefAddress?:number,
   Street:string,
   Street2?:string,
   Suburb:string,
   City:string,
   Province:string,
   Country:string
}
```

This works without a hitch, I can select items and my ngModel is populated with with whichever address I chose. Now however, I cannot set the selected item in code when the user opens the page again to edit a previous selection and the list is reloaded, i.e I populated the `selectedAddress` with an address item when the page is loaded:

```
if (this.navParams.get("Address")) {
    this.selectedAddress = this.navParams.get("Address");
}
```

Full TS file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j1Ts4UPKl_5P9m-NMKLbgAJyla0ceoCU)

I made sure to only call the above function once all the items are loaded to the list first and with debugging I can confitm the `selectedAddress` prop is being set. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the whole `TS` file?

Comment: Sure thing, updated post

Comment: Are you making sure that your code is receiving your `navParams`?

Comment: Jip, debugged and there is data present